# Codeigniter 4 validation error callback_check_password is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

```
I am working in CodeIgniter 4 check password callback function. But validation error is (callback_check_password) is not a define.

 function  check_password($str) {   
            $uid = $this->session->get('id');
        $check_password = $this->Musers->checkpassword($str,$uid);
    if ($check_password==1) {
          return true; 
    } else{  
  return [  
        'check_password' =>  'Your current Password is wrong',
    ] ;
         return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Validation roles:

error in callback_check_password is not define. callback function in not working.

```
$rules = [
            'current_password' => 'required|callback_check_password',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
```

Comment: it is looking fore function callback_check_password() but you have  function check_password()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter 4 - Validation Custom Rule Function Quandry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352669/codeigniter-4-validation-custom-rule-function-quandry)

Comment: [Creating Custom Rules](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#id34)

Comment: I find myself here for the same reason as the original poster. I get the impression that in CI4 it is NO LONGER POSSIBLE to use validation callbacks as rules -- that you need to make rule classes or use closures. I'm not sure that's the case because the CI4 docs override and change CI3 functions without any comment that were changed -- yet assume we will read CI3 docs to fill in any gaps regarding things that weren't changed. It's really painful.

Comment: Specifically, in CI3 you needed to put the 'callback_' prefix on a callback rule. That functionality seems to have vanished in CI4 -- unless I'm confused.

Comment: Besides the CI4 docs being oblivious to the changes from CI3, I'm surprised the community here also seems oblivious to these.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the ability to conveniently list callback functions by name in rules has been removed in CI4. This was possible in CI3 by adding the callback_ prefix to the name  of the function and just listing it along with any rules in the pipe delimited list of rules in a rule string. The CI3 docs are very proud of this feature. The CI4 docs are oblivious to the fact this convenience seems to have been removed.

I think what you need to do in CI4 is to either create a full blown rule class and get the autoloader to find it as described in [the docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#creating-custom-rules), which is silly for a one-shot rule, or to use a [closure](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#using-closure-rule).

I vote for the closure rule to almost get back to the convenience of the old 'prefixed function name' method. You can do it like this

```
        $my_rule_list = [
            'my_field' => [fn ($value) => $this->my_callback_function($value)]
        ];

        $my_error_messages = [
            'my_field' => [0 =>    'The callback validator returned false.']
        ];
```

You have to use the array method of listing the closure rule rather than the pipe separated string 'rule1|rule2|rule3...'  because, of course, that was the CI3 way of listing a callback. That way doesn't seem to be supported any more.